# Check whether string is set, even if it's 0

Tags: php

What's the best way of writing:

```
if(!$this->uri->segment('4') && $this->uri->segment('4') != 0)
```

This is far too long winded. Just need to check if a string is set, even if it's 0.

Comment: @Shakti: [empty](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) has the exact same problem that the OP does now, in that it accepts `"0"` as "empty" (amongst lots of other things). In fact, notice: "empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var". That is, `!empty` is what the OP is _already_ doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is far too long winded. Just need to check if a string is set, even if it's 0.

How about checking for the length of the string?

```
if (strlen($this->uri->segment('4')) > 0)
```

*EDIT* For explicitness, I've added > 0, so it may be a little more descriptive what it is exactly you expect. This isn't necessary, however.

Comment: Yea, I suspect that this will be the solution.

Comment: You have a typo (duly fixed).

Answer (score 3):

[isset()](http://www.php.net/isset)

EDIT: nope this is not a var its a method..

> Just need to check if a string is set, even if it's 0.

```
if($this->uri->segment('4') != '')
```

but i dont think this is what you are trying to do.

it depends on what this method returns and what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @Rubinus: Your edit seems unlikely to be helpful for what the OP describes as "a string".

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal yeah i know. but Questionair is really unprecise what he wants to know and what the method returns. (he is checking against != 0 but wants to know for a string...)

Comment: @Rufinus: Dynamic typing means `"0" != 0` is valid. Look at the criteria for PHP's `empty` function, which describes what the OP is trying to workaround.

Comment: @Tomalak: if as he commented on your answer want to chekc if a id is given or not, i still would go with > 0 (an id should not be 0)

Comment: @Rufinus: But that does not account for all the cases.

Comment: @Tomalak: Dynamic Typing means "0" == 0 AND "0" !== 0. but i'm sure you where trying to say that :-)

Comment: @Rufinus: Nowhere have you previously brought up `!==`, which is completely different to what we're talking about.

Comment: @Tomalak: if it is really always a id, and this id has to be >0 then an 'intval($this->url->segment('4')) > 0`. but as long as he dont writes what the possabilities are, its a waste to discuss.

Comment: @Rufinus: "always a id" should be a contract of the piece of code, not something that you just hope the user abides by. Code _robustly_!

Comment: @Tomalak: my last comment on this... when a user enteres a string, intval will convert it to 0 so all is good. when you read my previous comment again, i layed out the exact enviroment in which it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The first clause isn't "correct" anyway, as you've discovered by having to write the second one. You also have to consider `FALSE` and the empty string (`""`). Code like `if ($var)` is lazy and, usually, *wrong*.

The correct approach for testing a *variable* is the PHP function `isset`. However, assuming `$this->uri->segment('4')` is a function call, the result will always be "set". It can never not be set. So it seems unlikely to be that you can do much here.

What criteria are you *really* looking for?

Perhaps your function `segment` returns `null`? So write `if (!is_null($this->uri->segment('4')))`.

Or perhaps you're looking for the empty string? So write `if ($this->uri->segment('4') != "")`.

Comment: I'm looking to test if an ID has been passed in the 4th segment of the uri. This happens before I check that ID against a table in my database.

Comment: @Michael: I am not familiar with the object you are using (in fact, you have not provided any information about it). But it does sound like you just want to test for an empty string.

Comment: I know, rushed question, my bad. :) In more detail, this is codeigniter's uri helper function. So we'd head to site.com/edit_page/4 and it will hook up to the page details in the database. Could I ask, what are the repercussions of if($var), and why is it lazy?

Comment: @Michael: The repercussions are what you have run into: `if (!$var)` does *NOT* mean `if (!isset($var))`, and similar is true for your `if (!foo())` case. It's lazy because there's no reason not to write the correct code in the first place (for those that know about it, that is), but people do it "to save on typing".

Comment: "It's lazy because there's no reason not to write the correct code". If your intent is to accept every value that doesn't evaluate to (bool) false, e.g. all values % [null, false, 0, "0"], it is a perfectly correct statement. I do agree though that I like my statement expressive of what I'm expecting.

Comment: I like yours too. For some reason, although this is a codeigniter specific problem, isset() will error when checking the uri segments.

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   if ( strlen($this->uri->segment('4')) )
   {}
   ```
2. ```
   if ( strlen($this->uri->segment('4')) !== "" )
   {}
   ```